# How to change the font color when using out.print(<text>) in JSP?

Tags: jsp, fonts, colors

I want to print certain text using a JSP script which should be blue in color. I think this can be done by using CSS. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me the code. Also, is it possible to change the text color using some inbuilt JSP functions or perhaps HTML tags? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this...

```
<%
    String aString = "FooBar";
%>
Hello <span class="blueText"><%= aString %></span>.
```

This should print: "Hello FooBar." on the screen. To make FooBar really blue, define a CSS class like this:

```
.blueText {
   color: blue;
}
```

In general you want to use HTML to mark up your data and CSS to define how this data should be presented/rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the ouput of JSP file is HTML/Text. So you can apply css to jsp like how you do with html.

```
....
....
<div id="header" class="dark">
jsp or html here
</div>
....
....
```

And in your css file. You add style definitions.

```
#header
{
font-size:40px;
}
.dark
{
color:red;
}
```

To refer css file in your JSP page.
Add the below lines inside the header tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
<%@include file="style.css" %>
</style>
```

Use the correct path and filename of your stylesheet in place of "style.css."